# Mongoose model Schema with reference array: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "["5f09b....,5f0d...."]"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

i have already seen this article : [Mongoose model Schema with reference array: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24829355/mongoose-model-schema-with-reference-array-casterror-cast-to-objectid-failed-f)

But can't figure how can i solve my problem as i think i'm passing the correct value.

my category schema :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: true,
      maxlength: 32,
      unique: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Category", categorySchema);
```

product schema where i ref category:

```
const { ObjectId } = mongoose.Schema;
category: [
  {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
    required: true,
  },
],
```

error i get :

```
Error: Product validation failed: category: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "["5f09bc7d75350639906e0822,5f0df6442400aa0344d64347"]" at path "category"

stringValue: '"["5f09bc7d75350639906e0822,5f0df6442400aa0344d64347"]"',
messageFormat: undefined,
kind: '[ObjectId]',
value: '["5f09bc7d75350639906e0822,5f0df6442400aa0344d64347"]',
path: 'category',
reason: [CastError] } },
```

how i make the product :

```
form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "Problem with image",
      });
    }
    //destructure the fields
    const { name, description, price, category, stock } = fields;
    if (!name || !description || !price || !category || !stock) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: "All fields are required!",
      });
    }
    //TODO : rescrition on fields
    let product = new Product(fields);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that fields.category is a string.You have to convert it to an array.

this should work :

```
form.parse(req, (err, fields, file) => {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: "Problem with image",
          });
        }
        //destructure the fields
        const { name, description, price, category, stock } = fields;
        if (!name || !description || !price || !category || !stock) {
          return res.status(400).json({
            error: "All fields are required!",
          });
        }
        fields.category = category.split(",");
        //TODO : rescrition on fields
        let product = new Product(fields);
```